# How to move Alpine mail on a different machine on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, email, alpine-mail

I have to move my Alpine account/mail/address book from an old pc to a newer one. I'm searching through the documentation and can't find useful informations about this.

As Alpine is installed to the second pc, copying the `/home/old_username/mail` directory of the old pc over the `/home/new_username/mail` directory of the new pc (created by Alpine after installation) is enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 3 files and a directory that I'm aware of, that you will need to copy.

1. The file `~/.pinerc`. This is the Alpine config file.
2. The file `~/.addressbook`. This is the Alpine addressbook.
3. The file `/var/spool/mail/username`. This is the inbox for user `username`. NOTE: apparently the "real" location is now `/var/mail`, and `/var/spool/mail` which is now a symlink to that. But I'm still using `/var/spool/mail` from force of habit.
4. The directory where Alpine stores its mail folders. This is 
   configurable and defaults to `~/Mail`. It's controlled by the 
   variable `folder-collections` in `~/pinerc`.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. I could import all the email configurations, address book and emails with their folder structure. In my case, the system user had the same name. It could be a problem doing this with a user with a different username?

Comment: Hi @SashaGrievus. You write: "In my case, the system user had the same name. It could be a problem doing this with a user with a different username?". I don't understand your question, sorry. Can you give me an example of what you are talking about?

Comment: Sorry, was a question just for the sake of precision. I was thinking that, precisely, in my main question I was talkin'about an old machine with an  /home/old_username/mail and a new machine with a /home/new_username/mail (old_username could be *not* equal to new_username). In that case, this process, I guess, it's still possible? Or maybe pinerc must be edited replacing the string old_username with new_username? And this is sufficient?

Comment: Oh, I see. I think everything should work the same regardless whether those user names are the same.